# Strategy for earning the Wheels of Hazard pin in Bad Company 2?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I just can't seem to earn the "Wheels of Hazard" pin in Bad Company 2 (in a round, score three roadkills in any vehicle).

The quadbike on Port Valdez seems like an obvious choice, but I always either get sniped off or exploded when I get close.  Often it seems like a direct hit doesn't even register.

What would be a good map and/or vehicle to focus my attempts, and is there a trick to getting the roadkill to register?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For picking up roadkills, Conquest mode is probably the best. There tend to be more vehicles available than in other modes, and in more predictable locations.

You might also find that it's actually easier to pick up roadkills in armor than with a quad bike. Quads have a relatively low area to impact the target with, and you can get roadkills by trapping opponents against a wall or other obstacle with an armored vehicle.

That being said, the most important trick to getting roadkills is to drive a lot of vehicles. However, try not to make it too obvious that you're going for the roadkill. When you do that, you tend to move in a straight line towards opposing infantry, which makes you an excellent target, and it rarely works, since the guy on the ground can change direction a lot quicker than you can in the vehicle. You're better off just doing a lot of driving and picking up the kills in the course of the game.

Answer (score 1):

I had decent luck on Valparaiso rush, first stage.  As attacker, grab the quad bike and run it through the valley between the small hills on the south/left side.  There are usually defenders in the area hiding behind the hills and you are likely to get someone before getting picked off.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and heard many people saying that the best way was to get the UAV and roadkill people from behind. You can find many videos on how to do that, on youtube. Anyhow I suck at UAV/helis, just can't control them so this didn't work for me. 
What worked for me is this: look for a server with **high ticket** in conquest mode. Those games take loooong to finish so you have plenty of time to roadkill people. Atacama was my choice, I took that hummer and ran over snipers that always stick by the side of the A or C walls.

Answer (score 1):

Play on Atacama Desert, use the Cobra or HMVEE and go around the whole map and kill poeple in their base as they're spawning or AFK.

It's cheap but that's how I got mine.